# MAMP http request to port 80 returns connection refused error on port 8888

Tags: wordpress, http, server, port, mamp

I have set the Apache port to 80 on MAMP. The the request to "http://localhost/MAMP" (the startup page,  port 80) works fine. However, when I try to access the "http://localhost/" it gives a connection refused error. on port 8888?

[the MAMP page works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECiGZ.png)

[http://localhost/ redirects to localhost:8888 resulting in error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoftH.png)

[http request and corresponding error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTvlu.png)

Things I have tried:

1. disable mac built-in Apache with `apachectl stop`  - Does not work
2. check activity on port 80 (nothing suspicious) - Does not work
3. port 8888 works fine but my goal is to have an simple url format to able to use xdebug with it.

Comment: Show a screenshot of what you mean

Comment: @CaiusJard added screenshots!

Comment: So the client issues a request to http://local host and the response is a HTTP 30x telling it to go to 8888? What do you mean by "error on port 8888l vs "port 8888 works fine"?